# JavaNNS on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install JavaNNS on Ubuntu 14.04, the manual simply says unpack the download into one directory, this directory should contain `examples`, `JavaNNS.jar`, and `manual`. Then you're suppose to open an terminal and run `java -jar JavaNNS.jar` at that point a window pops asking to set the directory for installation, this is when `libSNNS_jkr.so` is created in the directory specified.

Below is the error message I get after  I attempt installation. Does anyone know how to successfully install this?

```
~> pwd
/home/user/Desktop/jnns
~> ls
examples  JavaNNS.jar  libSNNS_jkr.so  manual
~> java -jar JavaNNS.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/user/Desktop/jnns/libSNNS_jkr.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
java.lang.Exception: The system couldn´t find the library SNNS_jkr
JavaNNS couldn´t start.
at javanns.Network.<init>(javanns/Network.java:48)
at javanns.Snns.<init>(javanns/Snns.java:151)
at javanns.Snns.appletMain(javanns/Snns.java:278)
at javanns.Snns.main(javanns/Snns.java:258)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaNNS requires a library to work. The library it requires is the kernel from SNNS. SNNS was an X Windows application and a 'kernel', but the X Windows part was effectively deprecated in favour of JavaNNS... JavaNNS uses the original SNNS 'kernel' though.

If I remember correctly, JavaNNS was distributed with the SNNS kernel, precompiled for various platforms, but I it is all quite ancient stuff so I'm not particularly surprised it has some problems. Probably wouldn't work even if it found the library.

I did create Debian packaging for the SNNS kernel and JavaNNS last year (I used SNNS about 10 years ago and wanted to again last year), which you are welcome to help yourself to if you like. I offer no warranty or support of course, but it should work in so far as it will build, install, the package dependencies between them work, and it will find the library! At least, it worked on by Debian system at the time (which was probably Squeeze).

The repositories on git for both are checked in pristine sources with the debian packaging committed afterwards (neither had a git repo previously so I couldn't fork):

- [JavaNNS git repo](https://github.com/mwri/javanns)
- [SNNS git repo](https://github.com/mwri/snns)